# Eclipse, How do I execute code in a bundle after the WorkBench window has been created?

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

So I have a bundle that needs access to the workbench window to add some items to a menu programmatically, which I can do fine.

But what I run into is when there's a race condition where my bundle is started before the workbench window is finished being instantiated and it will spit out an error about the workbench not existing yet when my bundle tries to add stuff to a menu with code.

So is there an extension point or something that I can use to tell the program to execute such and such code after the workbench window has loaded?   I don't want to muck around with start levels for my bundles.

Answer (score 0):

- In Eclipse 3 you can register org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchWindowAdvisor to listen for window lifecycle events.
- If your items are not dynamically you can add them via plugin.xml (instead of programmatically adding them). Eclipse will load this extensions when appropriate and you don't have to worry about the lifecycle.